# PowerShell Regex with "." PowerShell

Tags: regex, string, powershell

i want to replace a part of some Strings in a loop with PowerShell

example string

`testvm029.vmxxx`

I want to replace everything at .vmxxx. Every string has another length but all ends with `.vm...` So the result should be: `testvm029`

I tried the following Script:

`Foreach($String in $Strings) {`

`$StringTest = $String -replace "(.vm)(.+)","$null"`

`}`

Of course this kills my String on the first `vm` and not at `.vm...`
result:
`test`

how can i achieve my goal?

EDIT: .vm is not the last '.' of my String so something like that:
`test123.vmabc.string`

I want to cut it after `.vm`

Comment: Thx, but your Regex does not work for me. And i edited the question...

Comment: `$String -replace '\.vm.*$'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
$String -replace '\.vm.*'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KK22bU/1/)

The pattern will find the first `.vm` substring (with `\.vm`) and then match the rest of the string (with `.*`). The match will be replaced with an empty string (it is used by default, but you may write it explicitly, `$String -replace '\.vm.*', ''`).